# Display a Commerce Option Set select list in views?

Tags: views, commerce

I have a Commerce product type that references an option set which I would like to display in views using referenced product... I have no problem displaying any other field data from the node, but the select list is simply elusive. Is it just not possible to render a select list in views?

I've googled around for like for hours... Sorry if this an obvious answer for everyone, I'm just stumped to the max!!